# Identifying what contributes to the increase in one variable

Tags: regression, logistic, model, causality

Say I have a dataset with several continuous and categorical variables, and I want to identify what variables (values or properties of these variables) may cause one of the continuous variables to increase. How can I model this problem?

Several approaches come to mind (e.g. **logistic regression**, **ANOVA**, **decision trees**) but most (all?) of them require that I define a **condition** on my target variable and thus make it a **categorical** variable and/or treat the problem as a **classification problem**.

But what if my **dependent** variable is a continuous variable and I am looking for properties of the independent variables (continuous and categorical) that make my dependent variable to increase? Is **linear regression** the best I can do? What if my goal is to find **ranges** of the predictors that correlate statistically with increases of my dependent variable?

What **models** do I have available for this problem, and most importantly, what **questions** should I ask myself about the problem to identify the proper one?

Comment: is this sincere? linear regression? is this really causal-inference?

Comment: @charles Is linear regression really the right answer here? Note that the emphasis here is not on prediction, but in determining **combinations** or **ranges** of the inputs that cause a variable to increase. You may be right, but I want to make sure I am not missing any other potentially applicable methods or models here.

Comment: I'm reluctant to give advice. And don't want to be negative. But there are many oddities here:(1) why is increase highlighted? seems odd thing to emphasize. (2) why is logistic regression an option you're considering but not linear? (3) why do you think linear regression is only used for prediction? (4) causality is incredibly hard to prove. I would avoid using the word.

Comment: I think you would benefit from viewing Experimentation for Improvement https://class.coursera.org/experiments-001/lecture to understand how statistics is used with experimental design to optimise a process

Comment: Causality won't proceed from some aspect of how the numbers relate to each other. You could reasonably demonstrate causality by carefully controlled experiment, or perhaps by very carefully reasoned argument about the absence of any other plausible causal variables (ruling out any possibility of something like the first diagram [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5jR8z.png) for example). Typically if you're modelling - whether dealing with discrete or continuous response - you're only demonstrating association. If you don't really mean to demonstrate causality it might be better to clarify the Qn.

Comment: Thank you @charles. I understand your frustration. Your comment  was informative, I mean it, but just to be clear (1) I did not say I am not considering logistic regression, in fact quite the opposite. The same goes for linear regression as I acknowledged above. (2) I am not hoping to prove causality (I will rephrase). I thought (and wonder) if the fact that I am interested in possible explanations rather than minimizing expected prediction loss could inform the approach.